# Userwarning with lzma while importing pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've debian 8 installed on my server with python 3.7.3 and when I try to run this code

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'Apple':{'Weight':12,'Colour':'red'},
     'Banana':{'Weight':11,'Colour':'yellow','Bunched':2}
    }

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index') # convert dict to dataframe

df.to_csv('fruits.csv') # write dataframe to file
```

I get this warning:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py:84: UserWarning: Could not import the lzma module. Your installed Python is incomplete. Attempting to use lzma compression will result in a RuntimeError.
  warnings.warn(msg)
```

How can I fix that?

I've tried to compile python 3.7.3 again and installing python 3.7.4 (unsuccesfully because I got a gcc error)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UserWarning: Could not import the lzma module. Your installed Python is incomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57743230/userwarning-could-not-import-the-lzma-module-your-installed-python-is-incomple)