# UserWarning: Could not import the lzma module. Your installed Python is incomplete

Tags: python, python-3.x

After Installing Google Cloud Bigquery Module, if I import the module into python code. I see this warning message. Happening to me in python 3.7.3 Virtualenv.

Tried to reinstall GCP bigquery module
Expectation-in python code if we write" from google.cloud import bigquery ".Should not result in any error or messege.

```py
import os
import sys
import logging
from datetime import datetime
from google.cloud import bigquery
```

```
/home/informatica/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py:84: UserWarning: Could not import the lzma module. Your installed Python is incomplete. Attempting to use lzma compression will result in a RuntimeError.
  warnings.warn(msg)
 exit()
```

Comment: >>> import os
>>> import sys
>>> import logging
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> from google.cloud import bigquery
/home/informatica/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py:84: UserWarning: Could not import the lzma module. Your installed Python is incomplete. Attempting to use lzma compression will result in a RuntimeError.
  warnings.warn(msg)
>>> exit()

Comment: Please add the info from your comment to the question body.

Comment: The `Lzma` module is part of the *python standard library*, which means something is wrong with your python download.  I would try uninstalling and reinstalling python.

Comment: Hi Caleb, I installed python 3.7.4 but still this issue.

Comment: 3.8.3 installed using pyenv on CentOS and same issue. None of the fixes below worked.

Comment: Performing steps in this [site](https://tecadmin.net/install-python-3-8-ubuntu/) worked for me. You can do this even you already have installed python, there is no need to uninstall.

Answer (score 149):

If you compile Python from source, you must have the `lzma-dev` package installed, or it will not be built into python.

For ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install liblzma-dev`

For centos: `yum install -y xz-devel`

Then `configure && make && make install`

Comment: Where do I do that configure and make?

Comment: I ran into this issue from compiling the python from the souce code. So the configure and make is do in the directory of the source code.

Comment: @matt525252 The source code needs to be downloaded from python.org https://www.python.org/downloads/

Comment: @DarwinHarianto if you install Python from source go to the python source code folder and run commands `./configure && make && make altinstall` here.
Also I recommend using `sudo altinstall` instead to not to rewtite default python version.

Comment: FOR CENTOS:
Firstly
```sudo yum install -y xz-devel```

Then recompile python from source code

```cd Python-3.8*/```
then
```./configure --enable-optimizations```
then
```sudo make altinstall```

Comment: `./configure` can be found where your python is installed. In my case, it was under `/usr/src/python-3.x.x/`

Comment: Note that if you've compiled you're own Python distribution (eg through ```pyenv install```), you'll need to re-compile the distribution after installing the package.

Comment: If you use pyenv, you might also run into this issue. Installing lzma-dev as described and then `pyenv install x.y.z` and overwriting the existing installation, where x.y.z is the version you are using, resolved the issue.

Answer (score 62):

On MacOS and pyenv (https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/), I was able to have this warning go away by having xz installed with homebrew. Using version python 3.6.9 as an example

`brew install xz && pyenv install 3.6.9`

To use installed python, one needs to add this into `.bash_profile`

`eval "$(pyenv init -)"`

and start using it by running

`pyenv global 3.6.9`

Comment: for mac OS:
```brew install readline xz``` <br/>

https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems

Comment: I needed to run two more commands before I finally got rid of the lzma error:

`set -gx CPPFLAGS "-I/usr/local/opt/readline/include"`

`set -gx LDFLAGS "-L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib"`

After that, I re-installed python versions via pyenv, and no longer saw the lzma error. Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried the comments above and now I have a bunch of printouts in my terminal. Can you tell me how to undo the effects of these commands?  Thanks!

Comment: @NicoleGoebel Did you figure out how to get rid of the extra printouts?

Comment: I ended up re-installing python and requirements and it seemed to fix things ...

Answer (score 62):

I used other good answers from here and didn't solve the problem (Ubuntu 18.04, Python3.8), still get this warning.
Actually there is one more package is needed to be installed to solve the problem:

```
sudo apt-get install lzma
```

So the whole pipeline (run in the python source code folder):

```
sudo apt-get install liblzma-dev
sudo apt-get install lzma
./configure --enable-optimizations
sudo make
sudo make altinstall
```

Comment: This is exactly what helped me, thank you =) (Ubuntu 18.04, Python3.8)

Comment: This helped me on Ubuntu 20.04, Python 3.8.5.

Comment: @Li-PinJuan I'm not sure we talking about the same thing, but I thought using `altinstall` prevents from overwriting default Python.

Comment: my soultion: 
sudo apt-get install liblzma-dev 
sudo apt-get install lzma 
pyenv install 3.6.6 (reinstall)

Comment: For Ubuntu 18.04 this is the answer that helps. It is not enough to install `liblzma-dev`

Comment: code still seems to run fine even though error statement, what are some consequences of ignoring warnings like this?

Comment: @haneulkim at the moment I can't remember for sure, but because of this some of the python libraries (like pandas) did not work for me

Comment: It worked for me. 'run in the python source code folder' is important.

Answer (score 59):

On macOS, if you manage your python with pyenv and package with homebrew, you need to install "xz" first:

```sh
brew install xz
```

After installing xz, you can install python 3.8 by (I'm using 3.8.2 as an example:

```sh
pyenv install 3.8.2
```

Above will fix the problem.

Comment: This fixed it for me!

Comment: How is this different from Mika Riekkinen's answer?

Comment: I was about to post what worked for me, but saw that the same solution has been posted here. :)

Comment: @JoshuaSchlichting  There were differences. I assume the someone updated the answer.

Answer (score 25):

This solution* worked on my setup (Apple M1 with `pyenv`):

```
CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix xz)/include" LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix xz)/lib" pyenv install 3.9.4
```

*Edit (2023-02-08): Link removed following the helpful comment from Martin Delille.

Comment: Same issue on apple M1, but I get "command not found: brew" when defining both brew (/opt/homebrew/bin) and these flags in my .zprofile. Any thoughts?

Comment: Might this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18428374/commands-not-found-on-zsh

Comment: What do you do with this code? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Super!  Thanks!  Fixed the message on my Apple M1 chip laptop as well.  In python version 3.9.6 for me -- as a python reinstall alone did nothing.

Comment: This worked with my already installed python installation (pyenv). E.g. no need to install python again if you are mid project. @EgeCan I think what this does is tell the OS where to look for the binaries. I.e. when referring to xz the OS needs to know about xz.

Comment: @EgeCan note the `pyenv install 3.9.4` at the end of the solution, so when you use `pyenv` to install a version of python use this whole line in terminal and change the version from `3.9.4` to the one you want. Note, unclear to me if this is a once off or if you need all of the code before `pyenv` for every install.

Comment: Your link seem to be broken and unsafe...

Answer (score 21):

If you are using `centos` and compile python from source, you can install from following commands

For centos: `sudo yum install -y xz-devel`

Recompile python from source code

```
cd Python-3.8*/
./configure --enable-optimizations
sudo make altinstall
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed.

Comment: Exactly what I needed for centos! Thanks, Bro!

Answer (score 11):

See last comment on https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/27532

```
brew install xz # To pick up liblzma
prefix=$(brew --prefix)
export LDFLAGS="-L$prefix/opt/xz/lib $LDFLAGS"
export CPPFLAGS="-I$prefix/opt/xz/include $CPPFLAGS"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$prefix/opt/xz/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"
# YOU CANNOT HAVE THE GNUBINS in your PATH when you run this
PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-shared" pyenv install 3.9.2
python3 -c "import lzma" # should work and not throw "cannot import _lzma"
```

Comment: reinstalling python with `pyenv install 3.7.9` solve for me, not sure why ‍♂️

Answer (score 9):

What solved for me:

```
sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev
sudo cp /usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_bz2.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so/usr/local/lib/python3.8/
sudo cp /usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_lzma.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so /usr/local/lib/python3.8/
```

Answer (score 5):

I had built Python 3.8 from source on Debian 10 and some times couldn't start mlflow server at all and sometimes got warnings albeit successful launches and also every pandas import gave me this warning.

Here's what worked for me:

1. purged the existing installation.
2. did `sudo apt install libncurses-dev libgdbm-dev libz-dev tk-dev libsqlite3-dev libreadline-dev liblzma-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev`
3. built python from source again.

I never got the warning again and had no problems whatsoever.

Comment: You need to install these packages and then resinstall the Python binaries (run `(sudo) apt install ...` before running `(sudo) make`).

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution from: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/28219

I just ran: `CPPFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix xz)/include" pyenv install 3.10.0`

- OS: Monterey
- M1 chip
- pyenv
- python 3.10.0

Answer (score 3):

I did `brew install xz` and reinstalled everything, but that didn't do it for me.

What helped me was to add correct linkage for xz as well:

```
    export LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix xz)/lib -L$(brew --prefix readline)/lib -L$(brew --prefix zlib)/lib"
    export CPPFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix xz)/include  -I$(brew --prefix readline)/include -I$(brew --prefix zlib)/include -I$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/include"
```

Answer (score 2):

I see that

```
yum install -y lzma
```

Also runs without errors.

Comment: I was having this problem with pyenv install 3.9.2, 3.9.9 on Amazon Linux 2. Installing lzma modue just fixed that issue.

Answer (score 2):

My OS is : `CentOS 8.X`

Step to step run command below, then fix the problem:

1. `sudo yum install -y xz-devel`
2. `cd Python-3.8.5`
3. `sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/python3.8.5 --enable-optimizations --with-ssl`
4. `sudo make`
5. `sudo make install`

Comment: in step 3, you should modify the path to your python installed folder if it's necessary.

Answer (score 2):

note: For Linux/Ubuntu

Step 1: `sudo apt-get install liblzma-dev`

Step 2: `pyenv install <python_version>`. This will prompt that the version is already installed, say yes. This will cause a reinstall, this time "completely".

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to provide some info on what "xz" and "lzma" are.

`man xz`:

> xz, unxz, xzcat, lzma, unlzma, lzcat - Compress or decompress .xz and .lzma files

https://www.nongnu.org/lzip/xz_inadequate.html :

> xz is a container format which currently contains another container format (LZMA2), which in turn contains a mix of LZMA data and uncompressed data.

Well, as far as I understand, `lzma` is a compression algorithm and `xz` is the file format.

For example, on https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3106/ , there's [XZ compressed source tarball](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.6/Python-3.10.6.tar.xz) compared to *Gzipped source tarball* .

So if you don't need to deal with the `.xz` files with pandas, you could just ignore the warning and keep going. Otherwise you need to **reinstall python** and you alreay have lzma libraries installed in the system. The lzma library's package name varies in different distros/OS. For example, on mac it's `xz` and ubuntu it's `liblzma-dev`.

Also see:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/whatsnew/v0.25.1.html#io-and-lzma

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/b5958ee1999e9aead1938c0bba2b674378807b3d/pandas/_testing.py#L245

lzma vs zlib:

https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/compressors_comparison.html