# How to Install python3.8 on debian 10?

Tags: python, python-3.x, debian, python-3.8

i've installed `debian 10.0.4` yesterday on my pc.

it had `python version 3.7.3` installed on it , so i tried to update it to version `3.8.3` and now i have version `3.8.3` installed but when i try to install pip using the official `get-pip.py` it throws an exception . the details is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 520, in _get_decompress_func
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zlib'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 520, in _get_decompress_func
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zlib'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 568, in _get_data
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 523, in _get_decompress_func
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 23484, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 198, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as pip_entry_point
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 241, in load_module
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 709, in _get_module_code
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 570, in _get_data
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available
```

i must mention that the python (python2.7) and pip for python 2.7 is working , and i tried to reinstall python using source compilation and i got another error while installing it (zlib error)

Comment: How did you update python? In any case, a very important comment: never mix custom programs (and versions) with system one.

Comment: Pay attention to step 1 my answer below

Answer (score 34, accepted):

## Installing Python 3.8 on Debian 10

Building Python 3.8 on Debian is a relatively straightforward process and will only take a few minutes.

1. Start by installing the packages necessary to build Python source:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev libreadline-dev libffi-dev curl libbz2-dev liblzma-dev
```

2. Download the latest release’s source code from the Python download page with wget or curl. At the time of writing this article, the latest release is 3.8.2:

```
curl -O https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.2/Python-3.8.2.tar.xz
```

3. When the download is complete, extract the tarball:

```
tar -xf Python-3.8.2.tar.xz
```

4. Navigate to the Python source directory and run the configure script:

```
cd Python-3.8.2
./configure --enable-optimizations --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions
```

The script performs a number of checks to make sure all of the dependencies on your system are present. The --enable-optimizations option will optimize the Python binary by running multiple tests, which will make the build process slower.

5. Run make to start the build process:

```
make -j 4
```

Modify the `-j` to correspond to the number of cores in your processor. You can find the number by typing `nproc`.

6. Once the build is done, install the Python binaries by running the following command as a user with sudo access:

```
sudo make altinstall
```

Do not use the standard `make install` as it will overwrite the default system `python3` binary.

7. At this point, Python 3.8 is installed on your Debian system and ready to be used. You can verify it by typing:

```
python3.8 --version
Python 3.8.2
```

---

source: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-python-3-8-on-debian-10/

Comment: It works fine up to this point then you get stuck, if you want to get further. For instance if you want to pip install mod_wsgi you need python3.8-dev which can be easily installed on every Ubuntu system using apt but with Debian you get an error "Unable to locate package python3.8-dev". Google cannot find neither a solution to the problem nor a definite answer that it doesn't working.

Comment: Try to add ./configure `--enable-shared` key while installing

Comment: Thank you for this response. I was able to compile, but when I started "python3.8 --version" I got this error: python3.8: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.8.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
I suppose it is the same problem with the missing python3.8-dev package.

Comment: I'm not a fan if some tutorial adds random switches (like that sqlite stuff) and just installs a bunch of dependencies without clearly explaining what they are for / why they are needed.

Comment: Installation was fine, but was getting warning after following Linuxize instructions, [UserWarning: Could not import the lzma module. Your installed Python is incomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57773679/343215). The instructions didn't include the library, `liblzma-dev`.

Comment: What if I want to try to install using apt (without deadsnakes ppa) instead manually installation?

Comment: I used this code in a docker container and this Python version was the only one installed. Thus, it was fine to use `make install` instead of `make altinstall`. The advantage: I can call `python3` instead of `python3.8`.