# How to detect whether zlib is available and whether ZIP_DEFLATED is available?

Tags: python, zlib

The [`zipfile.ZipFile` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/zipfile.html#zipfile-objects) says that `ZIP_DEFLATED` can be used as compression method only if [`zlib`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/zlib.html#module-zlib) is available, but neither `zipfile` module specification nor `zlib` module specification says anything about when `zlib` might not be available, or how to check for its availability.

I work on Windows and when I install any version of Python, `zlib` module is available. Is this different in Linux? Does `zlib` need to be installed separately?

Also, what is the proper way to check for `zlib` availability? Is `import zlib` going to raise an `ImportError` if it is not available?

In oher words, is this the correct way to use `zipfile`?

```
try:
    import zlib
except ImportError:
    zlib = None

compression = zipfile.ZIP_STORED if zlib is None else zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED

with zipfile.ZipFile(file, mode, compression) as zf:
    ...
```

Comment: I would normally just test it, but I can't, because I always have zlib :/

Comment: Do you build python from source? That's when the fun begins.

Comment: Although on linux/mac it might happen with missing optional packages too, it seems https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+zlib+not+available+site%3Astackoverflow.com&ia=web

Comment: @AndrasDeak Actually, I do intend to use the same code with custom python builds, on various platforms. Anyway, I was hoping for a generic answer explaining how to correctly use `ZIP_DEFLATED` and not ever worry about it failing. The idea would be to compress if possible and just store otherwise.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- On Ubuntu if you install Python 3 using apt, e.g. `sudo apt install python3.8`, `zlib` will be installed as a dependency.
- Another way is to install Python 3 from source code. In this case, you need to install all prerequisites, including `zlib1g-dev`, (and this action is sometimes forgotten to do)
  and then compile and install python as `sudo make install`. Full instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62831268/13782669)
- Yes, if `zlib` is not available `import zlib` will raise exception, such as

```
>>> import zlib 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'zlib
```

There are examples of code like this in the Python standard
library. e.g. in zipfile.py:

```
try:
    import zlib # We may need its compression method
    crc32 = zlib.crc32
except ImportError:
    zlib = None
    crc32 = binascii.crc32
```