# Unable to update python from 3.5.3 to 3.8.5 on docker container

Tags: python, node.js, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to update my python version that runs inside a docker container, but even when i try to update the packages with `apt-get update` or `apt update` and then running `apt-get install python3.8` or `apt install python3.8` i got the following error:

```
apt install python3.8
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3.8
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.8'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.8'
```

I have already tried the answer on this link: [How to Install python3.8 on debian 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62830862/how-to-install-python3-8-on-debian-10)

More informations:

*My docker-compose.yml*

```yaml
version: "3.3"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USER}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_DATABASE}
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgres/data
    ports:
      - "${DB_PORT}:${DB_PORT}"
  web:
    image: node:12
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/app
    working_dir: /usr/app
    command: bash -c "apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3 wget && wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/3.5/get-pip.py && python3 get-pip.py && pip install opencv-contrib-python==4.1.2.30 && pip3 install numpy && pip3 install imutils && pip3 install pickle-mixin && pip3 install argparse && pip3 install requests && yarn && rm -rf get-pip.py && yarn start"
    environment:
      IMAGE_DIR_NAME: ${my_path}
      PYTHON_PATH: ${my_path}
      SCRYFALL_SCRIPT: ${my_path}
      DB_HOST: db
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "10m"
        max-file: "5"
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: According to [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/node), `node:12` is based on Stretch (i.e. Debian 9). You may have better luck installing Python 3.8 from some PPA or such.

Comment: You might be better off refactoring this into a separate Dockerfile, so that long-winded `command:` doesn't have to be repeated every time you start the container.  It's not totally clear why you need a specific Python version in a `node`-based container; can you use a separate container, built in a Dockerfile `FROM python:3.8`, that runs the Python component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I particularly suggest you to compile an image using multistage example alpine that will get smaller or even use a distroless with python3.8 and node12 is smaller and more secure container! but if you want a simpler solution have these source code available that works perfectly for your problem

here python and node image souce code
https://github.com/nikolaik/docker-python-nodejs

from docker hub image

```
nikolaik/python-nodejs:python3.8-nodejs12-alpine
```

and here distroless images

https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless