# How to update Python on Vertex AI notebooks?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am working in notebooks provided in the Workbench section of Vertex AI. I need an updated version of Python, but I only have access to Python 3.7 in these notebooks. I have successfully followed [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62831268/8565438) and if I run `python3.8 --version` in terminal, I get `Python 3.8.2`, which is good, but `python --version` still returns `Python 3.7.12`. If, following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40694528/how-to-know-which-python-is-running-in-jupyter-notebook) and restarting notebook's kernel, I run

```
from platform import python_version
print(python_version())
```

in a notebook, and I get `3.7.12`.

**How do I get a notebook in Vertex AI supporting an up-to-date Python version?**

Answer (score 13):

```py
#create a new conda env:
$ conda create -n python38 python=3.8

#Activate your new Python 3.8 environment:
$ conda activate python38

#install ipykernel when logged in the new env:
(python38)$ conda install ipykernel
```

Refresh the page and the new python38 env will be avaiable:
[image]
[image]

Comment: This answer worked when I accepted it, but no longer does when I tried again with 3.10.

Comment: or with 3.8, for that matter.

Comment: This answer works correctly for me. However if I stop and restart my workbench I loose the conda environment created. If I look for the kernel in the top right I can still see python38 but it returns me the error: failed to load kernel. By listing all conda environments in conda, however, python38 is not yet available. Do you have any idea on how to save the environment to use it after a workbench restart?

Comment: Added an issue; please +1 it: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/249804661

Answer (score 13):

For me, @ewertonvsilva's answer wasn't working.
I had to install the ipython kernel at user level then deactivate the kernel before refreshing the page to make the environment appearing on Jupyter Lab, All commands combined :

```
# create a new conda env:
$ conda create -n python38 python=3.8

# Activate your new Python 3.8 environment:
$ conda activate python38

#install ipykernel when logged in the new env:
(python38)$ conda install ipykernel

# install the ipython kernel at user level    
(python38)$ ipython kernel install --user --name=python38

# Deactivate the new environment
(python38)$ conda deactivate
```

Then refresh the page.

Sources :

[How to add conda environment to jupyter lab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53546634)

[Installing the IPython kernel - IPython Documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html)

Comment: Tried, I thought it worked, but the new notebooks are also running old Python versions, despite the name.

Comment: @zabop You can select the kernel you want on any notebook, in the top right section of the page.

Comment: Didn't work for me. (Yes, I changed the kernel and it's still old python version)

Comment: didn't work for me either, even though it says python38

Answer (score 9):

After a few trials and errors, I found that:

- Changes under `/opt/conda` will not be preserved when you change/stop instances.
- Custom conda env needs to be saved to `$HOME`.
- `conda activate $ENV` will not work, since `conda init` was not executed.
- `pip install` installs to `/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages`, which will not be preserved.
- `pip install --user` installs to `~/.local/lib/python3.7`, which will be applied to every python3.7 kernel, kinda messy.
- In notebook, `!pip` uses `pip` in shell, not in current kernel.
- In notebook, `%pip` uses `pip` in current kernel.
- In custom env, don't use `--user` flag, or it installs to `~/.local/lib`.

Run the commands in system terminal:

```bash
VENV=new_env

# create new env in `$HOME`
conda create -y -q -p $HOME/conda_env/$VENV python=3.8 ipykernel

# activate env
source /opt/conda/bin/activate ~/conda_env/$VENV

# register kernel to `$HOME/.local/share/jupyter/kernels`, so it will be preserved
python -m ipykernel install --user --name $VENV

# install your packages, WITHOUT `--user`
pip install numpy==1.22

# check package installation path
pip list -v
```

Now you can change kernel in Launcher (takes a few minutes to refresh), or the box on the top right of notebook. The kernel will be preserved.

In notebook with custom env:

```py
# use `%pip` in notebook, instead of `!pip`
%pip install numpy==1.22  # `/home/jupyter/conda_env/$VENV/lib/python3.8/site-packages`
!pip install numpy==1.22  # `/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages`
!pip install --user numpy==1.22  # `~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages`

# you may see the difference in custom env
%pip list -v
!pip list -v
```

Comment: Thanks! Currently, this is the only answer which works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.10 is now installed by default on the latest image:
https://cloud.google.com/deep-learning-vm/docs/release-notes