# Error No module named '_lzma' simpletransformers

Tags: python, tensorflow, simpletransformers

I have model trained on `colab` and now I want to use that in my `centOS7-server` like this

```
import json
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import mysql.connector as mariadb
from simpletransformers.ner import NERModel,NERArgs


model = NERModel('bert', './checkpoint-14000', use_cuda= False)
model_args = NERArgs()
model_args.lazy_loading = True

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/sp', methods=['POST'])
def addOne():
    try:
        prediction = model.predict([json.loads(request.data)['txt']])
        return jsonify({'OK': prediction[0][0]})
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({'ERROR': e})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

I use `python3.9`

but I got the `ERROR`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/milad/flask/./wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
  from myproject import app
File "/home/milad/flask/./myproject.py", line 4, in <module>
  from simpletransformers.ner import NERModel,NERArgs
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/simpletransformers/ner/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
  from simpletransformers.ner.ner_model import NERModel
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/simpletransformers/ner/ner_model.py", line 24, in <module>
  from simpletransformers.ner.ner_utils import (
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/simpletransformers/ner/ner_utils.py", line 33, in <module>
  from datasets import load_dataset
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/datasets/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
  from .arrow_dataset import Dataset, concatenate_datasets
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/datasets/arrow_dataset.py", line 62, in <module>
  from .arrow_reader import ArrowReader
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/datasets/arrow_reader.py", line 29, in <module>
  from .download.download_config import DownloadConfig
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/datasets/download/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
  from .download_manager import DownloadManager, DownloadMode
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/datasets/download/download_manager.py", line 29, in <module>
  from ..utils.file_utils import cached_path, get_from_cache, hash_url_to_filename, is_relative_path, url_or_path_join
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/datasets/utils/file_utils.py", line 30, in <module>
  from .extract import ExtractManager
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/datasets/utils/extract.py", line 3, in <module>
  import lzma
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/lzma.py", line 27, in <module>
  from _lzma import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_lzma'
```

Comment: Your local version of Python was not compiled with full LZMA support. That needs to happen.

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57743230/userwarning-could-not-import-the-lzma-module-your-installed-python-is-incomple

Comment: which answer should i use?

Comment: Look for the answers that mention CentOS. Do Google searches. Read documentation. Look at other SO questions and answers. This process has been explained many, many times before.

Answer (score 0):

I find my answer in [this](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/1298) just look at the Solution

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).