# import argostranslate.translate says "no module named lzma"

Tags: python, lzma

I have installed "argostranslate==1.7.5"

but when i try calling `import argostranslate.translate` in centos i'm getting

`ModuleNotFoundError: No moduel named '_lzma'`

I have tried all the steps in https://stackoverflow.com/a/57773679 but noting helps.

Comment: What's your Python version ?

Comment: python version 3.8

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it has worked when I try to run my app in python version 3.9.6.

I hope it will help someone sometime somewhere.