Unable to install pylzma on Mac
I am not able to install pylzma on MacBook Air M2. Can anyone help me out with this?
 ERROR: Failed building wheel for pylzma
  Running setup.py clean for pylzma
Failed to build pylzma
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (pylzma)

I tried to sort out this issue but I didn't find any solution.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

We need more info from you. What's your Python version? Can you include the COMPLETE error message in your question as text  NOT images or links.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57743230/userwarning-could-not-import-the-lzma-module-your-installed-python-is-incomple
